# Googleappengine - building a multi-service application with Maven

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, ear, microservices

I want to build a GoogleAppEngine Standard app that has a default web service, with dynamic scaling, but has a basic-scaling worker that runs periodically (and will need > 60 seconds to complete its work).

It seems like the most modern way to do things is to use services so I took a look at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting). I am using Maven so I followed the instructions and I managed to get the app to build and deploy, but I got some classloader errors.

I am very much a Maven beginner, so this may well be basic stuff, however, I could find no more documentation or examples other than this page above about how to structure the app as an EAR and configure Maven to build it. I then got sidetracked by [appengine-modules-sample-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java), which I think is the old way to do things. There doesn't seem to be any equivalent for the multiple service way to do things (and the Google Cloud Platform docs I find difficult to navigate with the plethora of older apis, software, plugins and services co-existing with newer ones).

What is the best app structure tree and configuration for creating the sort of microservices architecture as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/microservices-on-app-engine) in Maven?